# How would I log in on Facebook using a python programme?

Tags: python, facebook, forms, python-2.7

I have a Python programme that I have stored my log in details on, How would I get the python programme to connect to the Facebook login page and input my log in details for me and then log in or return something?

E.g:

my details are  in my main programme(Email and password), then I want to connect to Facebook, and have my program enter the details and send that off to Facebook.

**Main Python File:**

```
import urllib
import urllib2
def facebookDetails():
    url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'

    values = {'email' : 'somebody@facebook.com',
              'pass' : 'password',
             }
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: Take a look at [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: okay thanks, ive had a quick read but i dont really understand it, how would i use my code with it?

Comment: Consider using the Facebook API. Its much simpler to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    iuser = 'username'
    ipass = 'password'
    # You will also need to download PhantomJS
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(pathToPhantomJS.exe)
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
    email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
    email.send_keys(iuser)
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
    password.send_keys(ipass)

    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_n"]')
    login_button.click()
```

Comment: it opens my web browser but doesnt load the url? How do i fix this?

Comment: `driver.get(url)` will load the url. You provided the .exe for your web browser?

Comment: yes but i used firefox instead of that phantomJS will that cause a problem?

Comment: I think I know what you did. You most likely provided `firefox.exe`. You need to use `firefoxdriver.exe`. This may need to be downloaded separately. Give that a shot and let me know if it works for you (it should).

Comment: That worked great, Thanks alot :) however im just wondering is there a way to do it without using a browser at all?

Comment: `.click()` should work. If you want to not use a browser there's a lot more that goes into something like that. You can however use a `headless browser`. If you're interested in that look up `phantomjs.exe`. It's a headless browser that will do just that, perform webpage tasks without a GUI.

Comment: okay thanks so will that be much faster? and I know it should but its not. I also tried making it press enter using '\n' but it didn't work either.

Comment: Headless won't be faster. If you want faster look into http GET and POST. Possibly try on another browser? I don't have firefox so I can't really speak for it. I tested it on Chrome and PhatomJS and both of those worked